# How do I open Gemfile from Windows cmd shell

Tags: ruby, windows

how to open a gemfile to edit through command prompt in windows,

what is the command for that?

example: To open a folder we use cd "folder name"

similar that how to open a gem file.

Thank you.

Comment: CMD has no support for VFS (as do very few shells).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're in the directory where Gemfile is located: `notepad Gemfile`.